# Use string or array of char for filename?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have come across something online about strings. It says to use an array of `char`s for a filename input and not string. Why is that?

[image: Slide]

Comment: There is a lot of bad advice in tutorials online. This is just one of them..

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using an older version of C++, where `std::ifstream::open` accepts only a `const char *`, not a `std::string` (see [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/)):

```
void open (const char* filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);
```

As you can see, you cannot pass a `std::string` here.

In C++11 and newer, you can pass a `std::string` as well:

```
void open (const string& filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);
```

---

A better approach: use `std::string` to input the file name and the do `File.open(filename.c_str());` to open the file.

Answer (score 2):

That advice is basically wrong. The problem it is attempting to get around is that back in the olden days, file streams took `const char*` as the argument for the file name, so you couldn't directly use a `std::string` for the name. Of course, the answer to that is to use `std::string`, and call `c_str()` to pass the file name:

```
std::string name = "test.txt";
std::ofstream out(name.c_str());
```

These days, file streams also have a constructor that takes `std::string`, so you can do this:

```
std::string name = "test.txt";
std::ofstream out(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it is because of the prototype of `ifstream::open(const char*)`.  Personally, I would have written the code as:

```
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream testmarks;
    testmarks.open(filename.c_str());
```

But that is yet *more* complexity to explain, and this is obviously aimed at someone *very* new to C++.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong, and it's a wonderful way to write programs vulnerable to buffer overflows, at least as written in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The "open" function expect char pointer.

However it is fine to do this:

```
std::string filename;
std::cin >> filename;

std::ifsteam f;
f.open(filename.c_str());
```